# Swift - playground: mathematical functions ambiguous use of tan

Tags: ios, swift

In this code in play ground I git error "Ambiguous use of 'tan'"

```
let mytan = tan(2)
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already found a solution, but as your question was

> Why is this not working?

I'll try to add an explanation for the problem.

Like most mathematical functions, `tan()` is overloaded for the various
floating point types:

```
public func tan(x: Float) -> Float
public func tan(_: Double) -> Double
public func tan(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

All these floating point types conform to the `IntegerLiteralConvertible`
protocol, which means that `2` can be interpreted as a
`Float`, `Double`, or `CGFloat`. Therefore, in

```
let mytan = tan(2)
```

the compiler cannot decide which one to use:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'tan'
let mytan = tan(2)
            ^
Darwin.tan:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func tan(x: Float) -> Float
            ^
Darwin.tan:1:13: note: found this candidate
public func tan(_: Double) -> Double
            ^
CoreGraphics.tan:2:13: note: found this candidate
public func tan(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
```

On the other hand, a floating point literal like `2.0` is by default
interpreted as a `Double`, and that is why

```
let mytan = tan(2.0)
```

compiles.

Comment: `2` is by default interpreted as `Int`, correct? But because there's no `tan` function that takes an `Int` parameter (and apparently there's no default order in which it is interpreted next), the compiler can't decide which one to use?

Comment: @TimVermeulen: Yes, that's how I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I have to write the primitive in the form of float not int to fix it. Like this:

```
let mytan = tan(2.0)
```